# Have only one checkbox checked per row in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, google-sheets-formula

I am new to Google sheets, and I am having trouble writing a script to have only one checked box per row with two columns checked. I have two columns, E and F, both columns are all checkboxes. Each row can only have one box checked. If one is TRUE the other turns FALSE and vice versa.
Also how can a cell be locked if checkbox is TRUE, and the only way to unlock the cell is with a password.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out for info on how to work with checkboxes in Google Sheets and Google Apps Script: https://spreadsheet.dev/working-with-checkboxes-in-google-sheets-using-google-apps-script

You can use this to run code when a cell is edited: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite

You could essentially create something like this.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;

  // if a checkbox was edited
  if (range.getDataValidation().getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX) {

    // if the checkbox in column E was edited
    if (range.getColumn() == 5) {
      // set the checkbox in column F on the same row to the opposite value
      sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 6).setValue(!range.getValue());
    }

    // same with the other column
    if (range.getColumn() == 6) {
      sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 5).setValue(!range.getValue());
    }

  }
  
}
```

If you want to make it so both checkboxes are left unchecked when you click on the checkbox that's already checked, you could probably modify both the inner if statements to include this within them.

```
// inside both of the inner getColumn() if statements

// if you just checked an unchecked checkbox
if (range.getValue()) {
    // then do the stuff from before
    sheet.getRange...
}
```

With that change, only one checkbox can be checked at a time, but it's also possible for neither to be checked.

Comment: This worked!!! Thank you! Is there a way to unclick a check box once its been checked?

Comment: No problem! Be sure to mark the answer as the best answer so other people that come across your question can know what works. Also, I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but if you meant to make it possible for neither box to be checked, I edited my answer with a solution.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but I am not sure where to place this new bit of code, and I'm not sure how to send a screen shot of what I did or how to place the code in this comment section.

Comment: You can put the extra code within the curly brackets of the `if (range.getColumn() == 5) { }` block, as well as the `== 6` block.

Comment: Ok I put the code in the brackets, but I still can't uncheck one box without the other one going True. https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/13388889?key=8e75f759e3d85e8b19eb6fd3e37478d5

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. It still has to have one box checked